# Sort a List of users based on statistics from a seperate Table

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, logic, objectify

I have a table of friends where I can get `userIds`. I also have a table of Stats where the `Key` is `userId`.

I want to create a highscore (`List`) of friends sorted by the `score` in the stats-table, what would be the best way to sort this list?

I can fill an Array of friends stats like this:

```
List<Player> friendsList = getFriends(playerID, limit);
List<Stats> stats = new ArrayList<Stats>();

        for(Player player: friendsList){
            stats.add(ofy().load().type(Stats.class).filter("player", player).first().now());
        }
```

Now I want to sort it and return a List of friends (`Player`) + `score` sorted by the highest score.

Comment: Is `stats` already sorted?

Comment: @StefanWarminski It is not

Comment: I have added a solution that uses the details that you provided in your post. I have tested the solution and it can compile correct. It is not an elegant solution. I can provide you with a detail elegant solution if you want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be made more elegant if you use a HashMap for your friendsList or use SQL to sort with. But I decided to answer based on the information you provided, such that you do not have to refactor a lot. I can provide you with a lot more elegant solution, if you want that, just ask.

**Solution to your problem**

```
class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Player> friendsList = new ArrayList<Player>();
        friendsList.add(new Player(1));
        friendsList.add(new Player(2));
        friendsList.add(new Player(3));

        List<Stats> stats = new ArrayList<Stats>();
        stats.add(new Stats(1,100));
        stats.add(new Stats(2, 300));
        stats.add(new Stats(3,200));

        Collections.sort(stats, 
                (Stats s1, Stats s2)->s1.getScore().compareTo(s2.getScore())
                );

        List<Player> highscore = new ArrayList<Player>();
        for(Stats s : stats){
            for(int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++){
                if(friendsList.get(i).id == s.getUserId()){
                    highscore.add(friendsList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        Collections.reverse(highscore);

        for(Player p : highscore){
            System.out.println(p.getId());
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
3
1
```

**Additional classes for the purpose of testing:**

```
class Player{
    Integer id;
    Player(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }
}

class Stats{
    Integer userId;
    Integer score;
    Stats(Integer userId, Integer score){
        this.userId = userId;
        this.score = score;
    }
    Integer getScore(){
        return score;
    }
    Integer getUserId(){
        return userId;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure how you are usiong compareTo() with integers.

Comment: `Collections.sort(stats, s1, Stats s2)->s1.getScore().compareTo(s2.getScore()));` Is sorting the integers with an lambda expression. I just thought this was easier than implementing a comparator?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to sort `stats`. In my oppinion the easiest possibilities are:

1. let `Stats` implements `Comparable` and invoke `Collections.sort(stats);`
2. create a new Comparator and invoke `Collections.sort(stats, new StatsComparator());`

Now you can iterate through this list, get the `Player` by its ID and put it into a new list.